# How to display total views of all posts of one category?

Tags: categories, archives, views

Is there any way to display total views of all posts of one category? How to show that number on archive page? I have used this code to count views of each post:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key ='post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key,true);
    if($count=='' || $count < 0){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key,'0');
        return"0 Views";
    }
    return $count.' Views';}function setPostViews($postID){
    $count_key ='post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key,true);
    if($count=='' || $count < 0){
        $count =0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key,'0');
    }else{
        $count = $count + 1;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
  }
```

But how to count total views for one category and display it? Please help me!

Comment: lol. you know this code sets the minumum number of views for any given post to 5 right off the bat. Are you interested in accuracy or inflated numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $QUERY = new Wp_query(array( 
        'post_type' => 'post_type_here',
        'category_name' => 'category_name_here',
        // you can use cat id ...
    ));
    $counter = 0;
    while( $QUERY->have_posts() ) : $QUERY->the_post();
        $views = absint( getPostViews( $post->ID ) );
        $counter += $views;
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $counter;

?>
```

getPostViews() and setPostViews :

```
function getPostViews( $postID ){

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count;
}


function setPostViews( $postID ) {

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also explain as how the code works